# C# - Performance of static collections vs collections as fields of singleton

Tags: c#, performance, static, singleton

I would like to ask if there are differences in performance between static references to collections of objects vs having a singleton class and having the collections as normal fields of the singleton class.

Static fields are stored in a different part of the heap as far as I know so isn't locality of reference better when using singletons in this case?

Comment: I guess you mean the different generations when talking about "different part of the heap" but i'm pretty sure there is no difference in performance in these. The only difference comes when actually moving objects from one generation to another, but still the impact is close to non existant when talking about collections. You should be more concerned with the data inside the collection and if the collection is the correct type for your problem. Asking a performance question so close to the used language is never a good start imho.

Comment: Locality of reference for what? Bear in mind that in either case the field is only going to be a reference - and in *both* cases a static field is required. (For a singleton the static field is the one with the reference to the singleton itself.)

Comment: My advice would be [MeasureIt](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2009/02/06/measureit-update-tool-for-doing-microbenchmarks.aspx) yourself...

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I had the wrong impression that when a field is static then the memory for that field would be allocated 'somewhere else' in the heap. I wan't talking about generations - this is a misconception on my part, as I am currently learning more details about the CLR...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that is slow about static storage is a read or write to a static field. After you have obtained either the collection instance or the singleton instance from a static field there is no performance difference. You have an object reference now and are not touching static storage anymore.

Note, that the memory of an object referenced from a static field is not stored *in* that field. It is stored on the heap. Only the *reference* to it is static storage.

The performance difference between static and instance storage is also very small.

Now, what is faster? The singleton-instance variant is slower because you have to pass through two memory deference operations to get to the collection instead of one.